# How to pass a route to #link-to inside a component

Tags: ember.js

I have a component that lists countries. It is used in several places, the only difference being the place where the link-to is pointing.

How is this best achieved? Are components the way to go?

```
{{country-list countries=model route="someroutehere"}}
```

in the component i have a simple #each

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked"
  {{#each countries}}
    <li class="brd-b-g">{{#link-to routepassedtothecomponent this}}{{name}}{{/link-to}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: I wouldn't be using the components in this case. Simple looping alone does the job here right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. You just need to reference the property that you used to pass the route. Eg:

Template:

```
{{country-list countries=model myProperty="someroutehere"}}
```

Component:

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked">
  {{#each countries}}
    <li class="brd-b-g">{{#link-to myProperty this}}{{name}}{{/link-to}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

[Working example.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kahijopi/2/edit)